# type mismatch runtime error 13 access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I just migrated to ms access 2007 and created my own ribbon. 
In my form, I have this "print" button where if you click that it will open the "report form"

here is what I wrote in my VBA code:

```
Case "btnPrintRevisionEingabe"
DoCmd.OpenReport acReport, "Revision_Eingabe_rpt", acSaveNo
```

and when I clicked on the "print" button

I'm getting an error "type mismatch runtime error 13"....

Please help..
Thanks

Comment: hmmm why is that? i don't understand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try just the following

```
docmd.OpenReport "Revision_Eingabe_rpt", acViewReport
```

nothing after that. Leave out the **acSaveNo**. That should work.

Comment: @astander: thanks it works. How can I have it in Print Preview? Because when I clicked on the "Print" button it open the document but in a normal view, how can i open it in print preview? Thanks

Comment: Change **acViewReport** to **acViewPreview**

Comment: @tintincute So how about changing the accepted answer to this one?

Comment: @Remou: what do you mean? you mean your answer?